# Javascript filereader appears to be defined backwards

Tags: javascript

So i have some Javascript code that is verified to work. Here is the code with the details removed:

```
const imgPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
{
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsBinaryString(inputFile[0]);
    reader.onload = function(event)
    {
        resolve();
    }
    reader.onerror = function()
    {
        reject();
    }
});
```

I understand the code but it appears to me that it is in the wrong order. It would make sense to me if onload an onerror were defined before calling readasbinarystring but it seems to work in the opposite way. can someone explain what exactly is going on here?

Comment: `onload` and `onerror` are events, you can define them before you call `readAsBinaryString` the order does not really matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readAsBinaryString` will fire its `load` and `error` events asynchronously, so the code is OK - the current running script will have time to attach the load and error listeners before the engine actually starts reading the blob or file. See [the specification](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#readOperation) The first time the file reader's `error` or `result` could be set to something other than the default value (of `null`) is after this step runs:

> Wait for chunkPromise to be fulfilled or rejected.

Which takes a (tiny) bit of time.

If `readAsBinaryString` were synchronous, and it read the object immediately, you'd be right, it would only make sense to attach the listeners immediately - but in that case, there wouldn't be need for asynchronous callbacks at all, and `try`/`catch` could make more sense, allowing for synchronous processing.

Also note that nowadays, you should prefer [`FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer) instead of `.readAsBinaryString`.

Comment: So lets say if i were to somehow cause the code to wait for a long time could i miss the opportunity to assign load and error listeners?

Comment: Probably depends on the details of *cause the code to wait for a long time*. If you do something asynchronous between starting the read process and attaching the listeners, yes, that would be extremely suspicious and could fail in some situations. If it were me, in this sort of situation with *any* interface (not just FileReaders), I'd attach the listeners first, even if it turns out not to be necessary, just so I (and other readers of the code) don't have to even think about possible race conditions.